# Free pascal subrange

Tags: freepascal

I use fpc 2.6.2 and Lazarus 1.0.12 on a mac Mavericks
I create a variable like this

```
var
   MyVar : 7..200;
```

If I assign a value to `MyVar` outside the subrange of `7..200`, the compiler still accepts the value up to 255. If I assign 256 then the value in `MyVar` becomes `0` and if I assign `257` then `MyVar` becomes 1 and so on.  Has anybody got an idea what is going on?

Comment: Byte is eight bits so it can store upto 2^8=256 values. It's unsigned so allowed values are 0..255.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't created a sub-range. :-) You've declared a variable (using `var`). To properly create a sub-range, you first declare a `type`:

```
type
  TMyRange = 7..200;
```

You then declare your variable as that `type`:

```
var
  MyVar: TMyRange;
```

Attempts to assign a value outside that range cause a compiler error (for instance, in Delphi with range checking on):

```
MyVar := 201;
```

> [dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(22): E1012 Constant expression violates subrange bounds

It's usually a really good idea to **turn on range checking** so that the compiler will work for you. (It's usually a good idea to turn on overflow checking too, at least during development. See the rest of this answer for why.)

As far as the behavior you're seeing, the compiler will create the smallest size ordinal type that will hold the sub-range (in this case, a `Byte`). In this case, you haven't declared a subrange, but a simple variable, which the compiler fits into a `byte`.

As a byte can hold values from `0..255`, and you have declared a byte variable, the max value it can hold is 255. If you assign 256 (and don't have overflow checking turned on in your compiler options), the value overflows and wraps around to the minimum value (zero) + 1 (the number of bits it overflowed). Assigning `257` wraps around to the minimum value + 2 (again, the amount it overflowed).

Comment: While one should define a sub-range via type it's not really the issue here. What matters is that you need to turn on range checking. Also note that at least in Delphi turning on range checking does not guarantee that value assigned to MyVar will be in the sub-range. For example Readln(MyVar) can bypass this check.

Comment: @Avo: Clearly, the compiler can't check values read at runtime; I would think that's fairly obvious. Its job is long over. Where did I say "guarantee" anywhere? And where did the original question ask about `ReadLn`? It clearly says "if I assign".

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that you got something wrong. I just felt that you didn't emphasize range checking enough. And yes, compiler cannot check values runtime, but if you turn on range checking then compiler generates code that will do that. Also I wanted to point out that there are differences how Delphi and FreePascal handle this. For example MyVar := 201 will not compile in Delphi even if you turn off range checking, but does compile in FreePascal (unless you use Delphi mode).

Comment: I mentioned *both* range checking and overflow checking in my answer. I don't use FPC at all (I use Delphi, clearly), but if FPC allows it it's wrong. :-)

Comment: I don't think there's anything missing in your answer. I only wanted to make sure that the asker doesn't miss the main issue of needing to turn range checking on.

Comment: FPC *does* perform compile time range check, but *only* if you have range checking turned on.

Comment: My FPC also emits a warning without. On the original code (iow without Ken's type). With enabling range checking (-Cr) that warning turns into an error.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort You're right, it does emit a warning. I had forgotten that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe FreePascal actually creates a byte type variable (because it's the smallest type that contains given range), which accepts values 0..255. Number 256 requires two bytes 1 and 0 (0000 0001 0000 0000) in binary. The lowest get's assigned to MyVar. If you turn on overflow checking your program will raise an exception instead of silently cutting the value. You can do this via `-Co` compiler argument or using `{$Q-}` and `{$Q+}` compiler directives in source code.

As for assigning values below 7 or above 200 you can avoid this by switching on range checking using command line option `-Cr`. In source code you can also use `{$R-}` and `{$R+}` directives to turn range checking off and on respectively.

I would recommend always turning on overflow and range checking during development. It does have some performance penalty so you can turn it off in release if it starts hurting performance.

Comment: If you think subrange types are always rounded to byte, I invite you to have a look at the bitpacked modifier for records: http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refse14.html